# jQuery Ajax pass value and get results in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new to CI & I am stuck somewhere in getting value. Can I get example code in codeigniter to pass value from view to controller in Ajax, jQuery and get back result on same page?
In controller, on clicking checkbox I am getting value.

Controller:

```
function test(a)
{
   var id=a.value;
   alert("Clicked, new value = " + a.value);
}
```

**a.value** gives me value of selected checkbox. 
I need to pass it to controller. After passing according to query, there will be some filtered results which I again need to throw on same view.

Answer (score 1):

This is sample ajax function call . Try this

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url : '<?php echo site_url("Controller_name/controller_function_name")?>',
    data:{param1:value1},
            success:function(data){
                      alert(data);
                }
```

Comment: I am able to pass the value. I am getting the alert successfully. Now how can i view the data thrown on my controller? I have tried  $country_val=$this->input->post('value1');

Comment: echo the country val and check you console on firefox or chrome browser

Comment: I am not able to see echo results!

Comment: add the exit command after the echo statement so that it stops the execution.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller.php**

```
function getData(){
  $id= $_POST['id'];
  echo $id;
}

function test(a) {
   var id=a.value;
   $.post('<?php echo base_url()?>/Controller/getData',{id,id},function(data){
      alert(data)
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
class Test_controller extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }
  public function index() {
    echo __CLASS__;
  }
}
```

**Js**

```
(function(a) {
  a.ajax({
    url: 'Test_controller',
    type: 'GET'
  }).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
})(jQuery);
```